# Why would Craft Commerce only be using the dummy gateway?

Tags: plugins, plugin-craftcommerce

This maybe an obvious one but I thought I should document it here. After purchasing Craft Commerce and enabling your payment gateway of choice after disabling the dummy gateway, payments are still being processed using the dummy gateway only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in development mode then Craft Commerce will still use the dummy gateway. You need to disable dev mode to allow your payment gateway to be used.

Comment: This isn't _quite_ right.  You can use any payment gateway with Craft's devMode on - buy you can only use gateways other than dummy once you have a valid license.

I've successfully tested several gateways (paypal, manual, eway etc) - with devMode on.

Comment: Weird, I have had a licence and haven't been able to use the other gateways in dev mode. Thank you for clarifying it should be possible though.